# What was the purpose of this URL encoded php request against my webserver?

Tags: php, url

I saw this entry in my webserver log recently

```
179.x.x.x - - [19/Oct/2017:01:40:30 +1300] "POST //%63%67%69%2D%62%69%6E/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 244 "-" "-"
```

when I URL decoded the string it looked something like this format:

```
179.x.x.x   - - [19/Oct/2017:01:40:30 +1300] "POST //cgi-bin/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n 
HTTP/1.1" 404 244 "-" "-"
```

What were these people trying achieve by doing this?
Is this related the the "path info" feature of URL's?
does pathinfo allow execution of arbitrary PHP.
Should I take action against this?

Comment: We already got questions related to these requests [at least 5 times](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=allow_url_include%3Don).

Answer (score 4):

It is a common bot request looking for misconfigured PHP executable.

It is trying to reset your PHP settings to a whole bunch of insecure values to then further comprise your system.

It is hitting a 404 so there is nothing you need to do.

It would be worth setting up some dynamic firewall rules to block stuff like this anyway.

Fail2Ban is a good choice for that.

Comment: thanks, in regard to the part of the system that would potentitally be misconfigured - so I can check the value - is it hoping  "path_info" is misconfigured ?